# x86 and Vista 32 bit compatability

Tags: sql-server, windows, windows-vista

Can i run x86 version of Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Management Studio Express on windows vista 32 bit edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x86 **is** 32 bit, so shouldn't be a problem!  x64 is the 64-bit version.

You can run 32-bit apps on a 64-bit (x64) machine, but not 64-bit apps on a 32-bit (x86) machine.